# How to select neoclide/coc.nvim language server autocomplete suggestions in vim

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

[image]

I am using neoclide/coc.nvim plugin in vim on OSX

How do I select one of these suggestions, what is the command or shortcut to navigate and select them? I do not seem to have the ability to move around with vim standard navigation over the suggestion list window.

Comment: So `ctrl-n` or down arrow key doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to ask chatGPT before then I got the answer anyway. So basically ctrl+p and ctrl+n both works, but thank you too. This was a silly question from my part.

Answer (score 0):

`<C-n>` and `<C-p>` to select, also you can map `<tab>` to do selection, `<CR>` to confirm the suggestion.

```
function! CheckBackspace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction

inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
      \ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab>" :
      \ coc#refresh()
inoremap <expr><S-TAB> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-h>"

inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

Check `:h coc-completion-default` for the default mappings, and `:h  coc-completion-example` for more.